# Different dropdownlist component

Tags: css, html

I want to create a component as below:

[image]

It will be something like dropdownlist. I want to use this component every cell (td) of table rows. So my problem that to show second div(item list) under the first div but above the table rows.

Would you please help me about its css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would have the popout div fly above rather than below. The reason for this is that it will automatically be 'above' (in z-index terms) the elements above so it won't get covered up by successive table rows.

Secondly you will want to have something like this:

```
<div class="action">
   <div class="select"><!-- select box here --></div>
   <div class="popout"><!-- stuff here --></div>
</div>
```

Then activate it with CSS like this:

```
div.action {
   width:75px;
   height:30px;
   position:relative;
}
div.select {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
div.popout {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   bottom:30px;
   width:300px;
   display:none; /* it will be revealed on hover */
}
div.action:hover div.popout {
   display:block;
}
```

To make this work in old versions of IE you can add this JavaScript to the action div:

```
<div class="action" onmouseover=""this.className='action hover'" onmouseout="this.className='action'">
```

Then use a class of hover instead of the state:

```
div.hover div.popout {
   display:block;
}
```

I hope that's what you meant! :)

Comment: I think you also need {top:30px;} on the popout div

Comment: No, you don't need top:30px; because the bottom of the flyout div is positioned up 30px from the bottom of the select div. This makes the popup sit above the select div (this also means the arrow should point up not down :)

Comment: You can see a similar example on the thumbnails for my art gallery: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/art the info pops up above the thumbnail. This won't work in ie6 because it's a non-JavaScript solution - but you could make it work in all browsers by using the onmouseover and onmouseout as noted above.